# How can i declare a boolean variable in class in c++

Tags: c++, boolean

i want to know how can i declare a variable that contain boolean in it in the class section like as

```
  class account {
  char           itemName[50];
  double         actualPrice;
  bool empty= false;
  public:
  void           create_account();
 void           displayRecord() const;
 void           drawLine3(int n, char symbol);
  };
 void
  account::create_account()
  {
 do{
   cout << "Type the name of Item " << endl;
   cin.getline(itemName, 50);
 }while(itemName!=empty);
  cout << "Actual price :" << endl;
  cin >> actualPrice;
cout << endl;
cout << "Item Name :-> " << itemName << endl;
 cout << "Actual Price :->" << actualPrice << endl;
 }
```

Comment: What is your question here? are you stating that your attempt doesn't work? if so, what errors are there? by the way you can't initialise class members like you've done they should be done in the member initialiser in the ctor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a constructor to initialize class members:

```
class account {
    char itemName[50];
    double actualPrice;
    bool empty;
public:
    account() : empty(false) {} // this initializes the 'empty' variable to 'false'.
    void create_account();
    void displayRecord() const;
    void drawLine3(int n, char symbol);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, except if your compiler is C++-11 compliant (in that case the syntax you wrote is correct), otherwise you should add a constructor that sets inital values for the variables that need an initialization:

```
class account {
  public:
    account() : itemName(""), actualPrice(0.0), empty(true) {}
    [...]
};
```

PS: if your compiler is GCC or CLANG you can enable C++-11 compatibility through the command line switch **-std=c++11**